# XSLT1.0 replace multiple occurences of char with <br />

Tags: xslt-1.0

Have the following template that I use with xsl:call-template, but I need to use it to replace a `~` with `<br />`. I can get it to work with none HTML replacements but not when I try to use `<br />` or `&NewLine;` or `&#10;`. Any suggestions:

```
<xsl:template name="replace-substring">
<xsl:param name="original"/>
<xsl:param name="substring"/>
<xsl:param name="replacement" select="''"/>
<xsl:variable name="first">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($original, $substring)" >
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($original, $substring)" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$original"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="middle">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($original, $substring)">
            <xsl:value-of select="$replacement" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text></xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="last">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($original, $substring)">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(substring-after($original, $substring), 
                    $substring)">
                    <xsl:call-template name="replace-substring">
                        <xsl:with-param name="original">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($original, $substring)"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="substring">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$substring"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="replacement">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$replacement"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($original, $substring)"  />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text></xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="concat($first, $middle, $last)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please enough code (XML + XSLT) to enable us reproduce the problem. -- P.S. Your code looks over-complicated to me. Why don't you try something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339128/how-to-replace-single-quote-to-double-single-quote-in-xslt/30339654#30339654

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what's going on with the first, middle, and last variables but you should be able to just use a literal `<br/>` in your param...

**XML**

```
<test>one~two~three</test>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="test">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:call-template name="replace-char"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="replace-char">
    <xsl:param name="char" select="'~'"/>
    <xsl:param name="replacement"><br/></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="string" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="remaining" select="substring-after($string,$char)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($string,$char),$char)"/>
    <xsl:if test="contains($string,$char)">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$replacement"/>      
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$remaining">
      <xsl:call-template name="replace-char">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$remaining"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="char" select="$char"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="replacement" select="$replacement"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<test>one<br/>two<br/>three</test>
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked great