# Replace some specific words inside an XML node

Tags: xml, xslt, replace, xslt-1.0

I would like to replace this "~RS~" and "~FS~" inside the following node of an xml document to "CR/LF" and "Space"... so ('~RS~'=CR/LF) and ('~FS~'=space):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <NewsML>
    <DataContent>
            <body>
    <pre>
    ~RS~0ROSCOMMON~FS~TUESDAY 11 JULY~FS~~FS~No advantage.~FS~~FS~TV:ATR.~FS~Good~FS~
    ~RS~15.55~FS~ATHLEAGUE MARES MAIDEN HURDLE~FS~#9,402 added~FS~4YO PLUS~FS~2m 119yds~FS~Penalty Value EUR6800~FS~~FS~
    ~RS~21~FS~/1415-~FS~The Birdie Crowe (IRE) (157) (D)~FS~(Ms Bernadette Leigh)~FS~Mrs J Harrington~FS~6 11 7~FS~R M Power~FS~~FS~~FS~
    ~RS~22~FS~0-22~FS~High School Days (USA) (36)~FS~(Gigginstown House Stud)~FS~H de Bromhead~FS~4 11 1~FS~B J Cooper~FS~~FS~~FS~
    ~RS~23~FS~4~FS~Law Girl (FR) (36) (BF)~FS~(Mrs S Ricci)~FS~W P Mullins~FS~4 11 1~FS~P Townend~FS~~FS~~FS~
    ~RS~24~FS~P30-64~FS~Ballydarsi (IRE) (36)~FS~(J P Walsh)~FS~P J Rothwell~FS~7 10 13~FS~Mr B J Walsh (7)~FS~~FS~~FS~
    ~RS~25~FS~~FS~Cairnsforth (IRE)~FS~(J J Higgins)~FS~Michael Mulvany~FS~5 10 13~FS~A E Lynch~FS~~FS~~FS~
    </pre>
            </body>
        </DataContent>
</NewsML>
```

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30339654/3016153

Comment: @michael.hor257k, thank you so much actually it helped and solved my problem... I have used the "replace" template twice, once to remove "RS" and then remove "FS".
Thanks again!