# How to replace return (&#10; | &#13;) by the string "\n" in xslt 1.0 ? [XML multiline base64 to json]

Tags: json, xslt-1.0, carriage-return

I got a xml that I need to turn into a json.
I'm mostly fine except with a base64 multiline

```
<file>TU0...AAA
FOO...BCD
FOO...012
FOO...ZYX</file>
```

In json multiline is not possible, this should be rewritten in 1 line only as

```
"file":"TU0...AAA\nFOO...BCD\nFOO...012\nFOO...ZYX"
```

With "real" two-char string "\n" to concatenate each line.

Can I do that in xslt 1.0 ?

I know I can use translate but that's for one char only.
I'll try

```
translate(.,'&#10;',' ')
```

This will replace returns by space and maybe this won't break the base64 decoding of the json.

But, if i want to do it the "right way", I guess I'll need custom funcs.
In my case returns seems to be "
".
But if someone comes with a solution that works with all combinations (
  
) that would be great.

My primary target is chrome web browser but running fine in all browsers would be great.

Comment: If you want to replace a character with a string of more than one characters, you need to call a recursive named template - see an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30339654/3016153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get rid of the linefeeds you could use the `normalize-space($string)`function, e.g.:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xd"
    version="1.0">
    <xd:doc scope="stylesheet">
        <xd:desc>
            <xd:p><xd:b>Created on:</xd:b> Apr 22, 2020</xd:p>
            <xd:p><xd:b>Author:</xd:b> bwb</xd:p>
            <xd:p>generates a normalized text output of the file element</xd:p>
        </xd:desc>
    </xd:doc>

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="file"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="file">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could then still replace the whitespaces by something else( forJSON maybe with `,`)

If you definitely want the `\n`though, you could try the following stylesheet:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math xd"
    version="1.0">
    <xd:doc scope="stylesheet">
        <xd:desc>
            <xd:p><xd:b>Created on:</xd:b> Apr 22, 2020</xd:p>
            <xd:p><xd:b>Author:</xd:b> bwb</xd:p>
            <xd:p>Override default text() template by adding a search and replace funtionality</xd:p>
        </xd:desc>
    </xd:doc>

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xd:doc scope="component">
        <xd:desc>The string that should be searched and replaced by $param-replaceString</xd:desc>
    </xd:doc>
    <xsl:param name="param-searchString" select="'&#10;    '"/><!-- actually you also wnat to replace the whitespaces, that's why the searchString looks so  strange -->

    <xd:doc>
        <xd:desc>The string that replace any occurence of $param-searchString</xd:desc>
    </xd:doc>
    <xsl:param name="param-replaceString" select="'\n'"/>

    <xd:doc scope="component">
        <xd:desc>Override for default text() template testing for $param-searchString presence and calling replace template</xd:desc>
    </xd:doc>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., $param-searchString)">
                <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                    <xsl:with-param name="InputString" select="."/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="searchString" select="$param-searchString"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="replaceString" select="$param-replaceString"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="replace">
        <xsl:param name="InputString"/>
        <xsl:param name="searchString"/>
        <xsl:param name="replaceString"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($InputString, $searchString)">
                <xsl:variable name="token-before-first-match" select="substring-before($InputString, $searchString)"/>
                <xsl:variable name="token-after-first-match" select="substring-after(., concat($token-before-first-match, $searchString))"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($token-before-first-match, $replaceString)"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains($token-after-first-match, $searchString)">
                        <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                            <xsl:with-param name="InputString" select="$token-after-first-match"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="searchString" select="$searchString"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="replaceString" select="$replaceString"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$token-after-first-match"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$InputString"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: normalize-space(.) is a nice trick. My main issue was the multiline that is incompatible with json. Translatin &#10; and &#13; to ' ' did work too. The base64 strings are not supposed to be longer than 76 chars but it looks like it's not a problem for javascript atob() function that will post-process the json string I get from the xsl transformation.

Comment: If you liked my answer I'd appreciate a vote up ;-)