# xslt 1.0 Replace several characters

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have the following xml:

```
<item>value 1,value 2,value3</item>
```

I would now like to achieve the following via an output via xslt:

```
<item>value 1XXvalue 2XXvalue3</item>
```

I have done it with

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(item,',','XX')"/>
```

but there I only get

```
<item>value 1Xvalue 2Xvalue3</item>
```

Comment: The `translate()` function can only replace each single character with another single character.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Yes, of course there is. Did you not look at the linked question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30339654/3016153

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't shown to me yesterday :-(